# Create database with codeigniter's migration class

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, migration

I want to integrate Codeigniter's migration class to my project's build process. Can i use the migration class to create databases, or it's only purpose to keep up to date the database structure?

My migration class looks like this:

```
class Migration_base extends CI_Migration {
 public function up()
 {
   $this->dbforge->create_database('my_db');
 }
 public function down()
 {
   $this->dbforge->drop_database('my_db');
 }
}
```

When i run this code:

```
class Migrate extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->library('migration');

            if ($this->migration->current() === FALSE)
            {
                    show_error($this->migration->error_string());
            }
        }

}
```

I get this message:

```
Database error: A Database Error Occurred
        Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
        Filename: path_to_codeigniter/codeigniter/framework/system/database/DB_driver.php
        Line Number: 436
```

It seems the database must already exist before I can use migration class. Am I correct and need to write a wrapper around migration class where i create the database first?

Comment: The error does not (necessarily) mean you don't have a database system, i.e. MySQL, installed on the server. What the error means is that you have not supplied the correct [credentials](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html) to connect to the database system. That information is supplied in `/application/config/database.php`. You also have to loaded the CI database class. [Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html)

Comment: The credentials are correct. If i create manually the database (i.e. 'my_db'), i can use the migration class to insert new tables and colums etc. into 'my_db'.  The error message occur when i want to create 'my_db' with the migration class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suspicion that a workaround will be needed in order to create a database as part of a migration seems to be true. I don't know if it could be called a bug or missing feature but it will not do it as written.

The big issue is that the `_migration_table` that the class creates needs to be in the database being migrated. A classic "chicken or egg" problem.

Another possible issue, something the documentation assumes and doesn't address, is that the database to be migrated is the one that should be "loaded".

I think the following version of your `Migrate` controller will handle both of those issues.

```
class Migrate extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        if( ! isset($this->db))
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Must have a database loaded to run a migration");
        }

        // Are we connected to 'my_db' ?
        if( ! $this->db->database !== 'my_db')
        {
            //find out if that db even exists
            $this->load->dbutil();
            if( ! $this->dbutil->database_exists('my_db'))
            {
                // try to create 'my_db'
                $this->load->dbforge();
                if( ! $this->dbforge->create_database('my_db'))
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Could not create the database 'my_db");
                }
            }

            // Connection data for 'my_db' must be available 
            // in /config/database.php for this to work.
            if(($db = $this->load->database('my_db', TRUE)) === TRUE)
            {
                $this->db = $db;  //replace the previously loaded database
            }
            else
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not load 'my_db' database");
            }
        }

        $this->load->library('migration');

        if($this->migration->current() === FALSE)
        {
            show_error($this->migration->error_string());
        }
    }
}
```

Please know I **have not tested** this code. There may be syntax, logic or other errors. If nothing else, hopefully, it gives you a good starting place

Comment: Thank you for your time and your answer, it led me to the solution. One important addition: I hat to delete the database name from the database configuration file, because it throws an error if db did not exist.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know that would happen. How did you work around that?

Comment: I rewritten your code a bit. In the database config file i added all the credentials except the db name. Then i load the dbutil class, and check the database i want to create exists. If not i create it, then i can run the migration like a charm. The only downside i can't autoload the database, but i wrote a core controller and load there. It's work because my migration run in cli mode, and i dont extend it from the core controller.